# How to map internal DataElement's from the Dem to Dcm DIDs?

Tags: autosar, uds

How to map internal `DataElement`s from the `Dem` (Diagnostic Event Manager) to `Dcm` (Diagnostic Communication Manager) DIDs (Data Identifier)?

Let's say, I have a `DemDataClass` with `DemDataElementUsePort` set to `USE_DATA_INTERNAL` and `DemDataElementInternalData` set to `DEM_AGINGCTR`.

This `DemDataClass` is referenced in a `DemDidClass` as `DemDidDataClassRef`.

But how do I map this to the normal `ReadDataByIdentifier` service, which is handled in `Dcm`?

P.S.: I know how to implement it manually, but it sounds a bit weird that I can do it by configuration in `Dem`, but apparently not in `Dcm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AgingCounter (and other counters) are actually DTC specific elements, and are part of the so called **ExtendedDataRecord** of a DTC.

In Dem, you have to configure the `DemExtendedDataClass` and `DemExtendedDataRecordClass` and assign them to the DTCs.

These ExtendedDataRecords are not read out as DIDs over DiagService 0x22 RBDI, but with the DiagService 0x19 RDTCI (ReadDTCInformation):

- sub-function = 0x06
  reportDTCExtDataRecordByDTCNumber)
- sub-function
  = 0x10 reportMirrorMemoryDTCExtDataRecordByDTCNumber
- sub-function = 0x16 reportDTCExtDataRecordByRecordNumber
- sub-function
  = 0x19 reportUserDefMemoryDTCExtDataRecordByDTCNumber

The Dcm will actually pick them up for each DTC, using e.g. `Dem_SelectExtendedDataRecord()`, `Dem_GetNextExtendedDataRecord()`.

The similar approach is BTW used for the FreezeFrames/SnapshotRecords (see for the according subfunctions of DiagService 0x19 RDTCI).

Currently, I wonder, why you would do this with DIDs and 0x22-RDBI.

Comment: Good point, thanks.
Frankly I blindly read the customer requirement and thought how to get it done.
Something I should not have done based on my experience.
For sure this is anyway different across the DTCs, so having this for 0x22 would not make any sense.